# Man who has lost his wife gets dragged into a conflict between beings posing as gods and demons

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking to identify a (prose) story that's based in the Multiverse, with the main character, A man who has lost his wife and has two sabres and is dragged into a conflict between beings that pose as gods and demons.

I remember that one of his sabres was made of Damascus steel, on and was gifted to him by an old man, one of his sabres was called Julia.

I also remember a scene where the hero is being tortured by faceless mooks, but they wanted to keep him alive for whatever reason. Unfortunately that's all I can remember

Comment: What Multiverse, please? Marvel? DC? Weber/Evans? Michael Moorcock? D&D Planescape?

Comment: It was an original story that's part of the problem. Since I can't identify which part of the multiverse it comes from. Though I do know the main character is supposed to travel through several parts of the multiverse

Comment: @user14111: mooks are stupid goons, minions etc...

Comment: A time-frame would be helpful.  When did you read and how new (or old) might it have at that time?  Complete novel or short story ?

Comment: I read it maybe 6 years ago and at the time it was a short story but the author mentioned that it was to be expanded to a full novel